# Lubuntu three monitor setup - Make middle one primary - Tray icons not appearing (3rd monitor has smaller resolution)

Tags: 13.10, lubuntu, multiple-monitors, resolution, taskbar

I just installed Lubuntu 13.10 on my desktop. I successfully installed and configured ARandR. This is my current monitor setup (from left to right):

> 1st: 1920x1200
>
> 2nd: 1920x1200
>
> 3rd: 1680x1050

The problem is that the taskbar is extended to the 3rd monitor and the tray icons are hidden. Can't see them.

Also, I want to make the 2nd monitor primary instead of the 1st.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Similar problem - but with two monitors and not such good ones :-(

If I make sure the edge of the monitor with the task bar are aligned (xrandr or ARandR gui tool), the task bar still extends across both monitors - but I can at least see tray icons.

Not ideal - but I have yet to find any other solution.

4 minutes later :-)

Hmmm - just found another solution. right click on the panel, select Panel Settings -> Geometry. Set the Panel Width to Pixels, put in the width of the monitor you want it on. I have mine set to the left-most monitor - to get it onto the middle monitor, playing with the alignment and adding a margin should work :-)

Comment: Your "other solution" works really well. Thanks.